# What happens when git merge conflict file contains the string "======="

Tags: git, merge

When git merge fails with a conflict, the file with conflict will contain markers like `=======` and `<<<<<<<`. But what happens when the file's original content contains these string? For example, a markdown file may well contain the line `=======` to achieve the effect of

---

The result will be ambiguous. The line `=======` may mark the separation of conflict regions, or may be just part of file content. How does git handle such special cases?

---

Edit:

OK, I test it myself. git does nothing special in such case; it just leaves the file in an ambiguous state. What is the design philosophy behind this? That the situation is just too rare to worth any handling?

Comment: Seems like an easy test to try out yourself!

Comment: Never attribute to a well thought out design philosophy what can be adequately explained by a quick hack.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn’t do anything with these markers, except for inserting them when it detects a merge conflict. Removal and any handling of these markers, e.g. to decide which sections you want to keep, is entirely up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Git has not knowledge, understanding or concern about ANY of the actual content of your files.

When evaluating the files involved in a merge conflict **you should know** the details of the content.
It would be clear if those marks represent Git's indication of the conflict or the actual content and you should be able to, easily, remove what is NOT intended to be part of the file.